# Issue with converting Kivy app to APK using GitHub Actions

Tags: python, kivy, apk, kivymd, buildozer

I have successfully converted multiple Kivy applications into APKs using **GitHub Actions**. However, I recently encountered an issue when trying to convert a new Kivy app. Despite using the same setup and configuration, the build process failed with an error related to Java version compatibility.

```
buildozer.spec

requirements = python3==3.9.12, hostpython3==3.9.12, kivy==2.2.1, kivymd==1.1.1, pillow

osx.python_version = 3
osx.kivy_version = 2.2.1

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
android.api = 31

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
android.accept_sdk_license = True

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add

#android.gradle_dependencies =

#android.enable_androidx = True

#android.add_gradle_repositories =

#android.add_packaging_options =

android.archs = arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a

# (bool) enables Android auto backup feature (Android API >=23)
android.allow_backup = True

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# Python for android (p4a) specific

#p4a.url =

#p4a.fork = kivy

p4a.branch = master

#p4a.commit = HEAD

#p4a.source_dir =

#p4a.local_recipes =

#p4a.hook =

# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

#p4a.port =

#p4a.setup_py = false

#p4a.extra_args =

[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1
```

Error log

> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0864944Z Welcome to Gradle 8.0.2!
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0865239Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0865440Z Here are the highlights of this release:
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0866065Z  - Improvements to the Kotlin DSL
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0866899Z  - Fine-grained parallelism from the first build with configuration cache
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0867798Z  - Configurable Gradle user home cache cleanup
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0868210Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0869253Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0869573Z Starting a Gradle Daemon (subsequent builds will be faster)
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0870091Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0870292Z FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0870690Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0870828Z * Where:
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0872038Z Build file '/github/workspace/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/dists/UniversalConvert/build.gradle' line: 20
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0873120Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0873281Z * What went wrong:
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0873962Z A problem occurred evaluating root project 'UniversalConvert'.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0874932Z > Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0875961Z    > Android Gradle plugin requires Java 17 to run. You are currently using Java 13.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0877117Z       Your current JDK is located in /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk-amd64
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0877930Z       You can try some of the following options:
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0878590Z        - changing the IDE settings.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0879259Z        - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0880268Z        - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0880813Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0880952Z * Try:
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0881493Z > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0882517Z > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0883319Z > Run with --scan to get full insights.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0883730Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0884388Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0884870Z Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0885536Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0886401Z You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0887492Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0888124Z See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0888992Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0889159Z BUILD FAILED in 29s
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0889427Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0889433Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0889565Z   STDERR:
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0889781Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0890098Z [1m[INFO][0m:    STDOUT (last 20 lines of 45):
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0891067Z [33m       Your current JDK is located in /usr/lib/jvm/java-13-openjdk-amd64
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0892015Z       You can try some of the following options:
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0892725Z        - changing the IDE settings.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0893818Z        - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0894682Z        - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0895350Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0895660Z * Try:
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0896203Z > Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0897090Z > Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0897865Z > Run with --scan to get full insights.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0898378Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0898788Z * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0899495Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0900233Z Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 9.0.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0901152Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0902378Z You can use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings and determine if they come from your own scripts or plugins.
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0903582Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0904359Z See https://docs.gradle.org/8.0.2/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0905307Z
> 2024-03-22T22:51:38.0905692Z BUILD FAILED in 29s[39m